# Label text now showing up

Tags: c#, textbox, label

I have a label on a windows form that is not showing its text.  The label is getting its text from a textbox in another class called StudentSearch. It looks like this:

```
labelStuName.Text = StudentSearch.firstname;
```

When I run the application It does now show up with any text.

Comment: Going to need a better code example of what you're trying to do.  Is that assignment happening after you press a button or something?

Comment: `StudentSearch` is the other class? and `firstname` is a variable to which you've assigned the value of the other textbox?

Comment: @CNuts Yes. Let me get a better example

Comment: @secretlygayfrog Are you sure `firstname` has a value when you try to assign it to `labelStuName`.

Comment: So there is a label on a form and the text for that label is label1 and the labels name is labelStuName.  I have the code labelStuName.Text = StudenSearch.firstname; where firstname is a textbox in the class StudentSearch

Comment: @CNuts That is the reason. firstname does not contain a value.  It should be the value of the textbox

Comment: Well are you adding the value of the `textbox` to `firstname` somewhere?

Comment: @CNuts that is a mistake. Yes it should be StudentSearch.firstname.Text but it is inaccessable due to its protection level.

Comment: Sounds like you need to make it `public` so that the other class can access it.

Answer (score 0):

From what i see in the comments above, add the firstname property in you class like this `public Firstname { get; set}` or make the firstname field public.

then if you used the property your code becomes `labelStuName.Text = StudentSearch.Firstname.Text` or if you made firstname a public variable your code stays `labelStuName.Text = StudentSearch.firstname.Text`